# Using a split function in a Loop not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am receiving no output from the following code:

```
Sub spliter()

Dim text As String
Dim a As Integer
Dim name As Variant

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
     text = ActiveCell.Value
     name = Split(text, " ")
             For a = 0 To UBound(name)
             Cells(1, a + 1).Value = name(a)


             Next a
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

Using the 'run to' debugger, I can see the loops working fine. This was build originally as a splitter sub, with the Loop function shelled into it. The splitter sub works fine with 1 cell and by itself, but as I incorporated the Loop, the splitter function delivers nothing. I think this may be a array in an array issue.

Comment: To activate a Cell, use `.Activate` rather than `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` and Generally, i declare my split result like this : `Dim name() As String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're trying to put the data - you get the data from the ActiveCell which may be anywhere on the sheet and you paste it on row 1 of the same sheet.

This code will take the ActiveCell and cells below that and split the text string by the space and place each word next to the original sentence.

```
Sub Splitter()

Dim sText As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim vName As Variant

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    sText = ActiveCell.Value
    vName = Split(sText, " ")
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, UBound(vName) + 1) = vName
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problems :

```
Sub spliter()

Dim vText As String, _
    vName() As String, _
    wRow  As Integer

wRow = 1
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Or ActiveCell.Value2 = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "ActiveCell is empty!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
Else
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Or ActiveCell.Value2 = vbNullString
        vText = ActiveCell.Value
        vName = Split(vText, " ")
           For a = LBound(vName) To UBound(vName)
              Cells(wRow, a + 1).Value = vName(a)
           Next a
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        wRow = wRow + 1
    Loop
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @R3uK but unfortunately it still isnt working. With the debugger, I can see the code after the Do Untill and before Loop are not run. Do you think its the incorrect use of the Loop?

Comment: Nope I check the loop is working properly, but you will not enter it if your active cell is empty! So be careful when you launch the procedure! I updated the code as every splitted cell was written in Row 1 and so you only saw the last one splitted.